# UISplitScreenController with very many (over 20) detail views

Tags: ios, swift

I have inherited an app that I am to update to Swift. It currently contains a TableView that selects one of twenty-six specialized calculators, each in its own ViewController/XIB file.

My first instinct is to use a Master-Detail project template and gain the advantages of the SplitView controller. All examples I have seen for a Swift app of this sort use a storyboard with explicit DetailViewControllers and Segues. It seems wrong for me to storyboard 26 separate view controllers! Is there a way to programmatically select/instantiate the DetailViewController but still use the Master-Detail paradigm?

Answer (score 0):

What you seek to do is achievable, but not without some custom code.

Master detail is supposed to present you with a list of similar items in the master view, with the detail view presenting you with the contents of that item. The key is that your detail vc is supposed to represent data of the same type.

If you absolutely want to use the UISplitViewController to display unrelated app flows, you will need to programatically use the showDetailViewController method on your split view controller instance to manually specify the current detail view controller. AFAIK, this doesn't seem to be doable at all with storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Gilles Major confirms the problems I was encountering. I have therefore abandoned the attempt to use a UISplitViewController for this project, and have instead implemented a UITableViewController with each cell segueing to the appropriate ViewController.

Comment: I did upvote it, but since I'm a rank newbie with no reputation, it doesn't show, sorry!

Comment: Np, best continuation to you